# Como criar thread em loop em c#?

Tags: c#, thread, loop

Como faço para criar um thread que executa uma função, espera 1 segundo e volta a executar novamente em loop, até o programa encerrar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei o que sua função irá fazer mas isso seria um Thread em Loop.

```
using System.Threading;

...

Thread thread = new Thread(tarefa);
thread.Start();

public void tarefa()
{
  while(true)
  {
     ...
     anotherFunction();
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
  } 
}
public void anotherfunction()
{
  ...
}
```

Resumindo voce cria um Thread apontando para o metodo tarefa() que executa em loop (nesse caso eterno) o metodo anotherfunction() e espera um segundo para executar novamente

Comment: Era isso que eu estava querendo fazer, eu só esqueci de usar a função sleep.

Comment: Opa beleza, não esqueça de utilizar um Thread.Abort(); no seu programa, caso contrario essa Thread vai ficar "aberta" eternamente, em uma utilização simples  pode não fazer diferença, mas em larga escala, como por exemplo usar ela pra comunicação, se esquecer de ir abortando sobrecarrega o processamento.